# 3D plotting of a time-dependent function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a function *f(x,y,t)*, where for each time point *t* I have a 2D line plot of *x* vs. *y*. I would like to somehow stack all these 2D plots next to each other so that I see the evolution in time *t* (but not an animation, just a stationary plot). Both *x* and *y* variables hold 100 values, and I repeat the calculation *t=3500* times. I've organized the output of a function in a 2x100x3500 matrix.

I know that there is a very simple way to make a 3D plot of this matrix, but I have big trouble finding it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`waterfall`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waterfall.html)

```
figure
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(30);
waterfall(X,Y,Z)
```

[image]

Comment: My main trouble is that I'm not sure how to organize the data so that I can use it in a meshgrid. Currently I have two matrices, showing how x evolves through t (so, dimensions are 100x3500, a 100-member _x_ vector for every of 3500 time points), and another equivalent but for y and t. I suppose that for the waterfall function my x and t should represent X and Y, while the height Z should be represented by y, but I don't know how to put it in the right format. Any advice?

Comment: @MarkoF you said you had a line plot of `x(y)` at each instant `t`. Then you only need to put all those time instances next to one another in a plot. A waterfall plot might not be useful though when you have 3500 lines to plot, you might want to look into things like a `surface` in that case.

Comment: I understand, but from what I've seen these days of surface-plotting functions like surf and waterfall, they all ask for the data based on a fixed (mesh)grid. In my case, at each instant `t` I indeed have a line plot of `x(y)`, but the `x` values are always different across all moments in time. I don't have a fixed grid at all.

Comment: @MarkoF Ah, yea, that makes it difficult. Then your only option is probably to loop over a `plot3` using `hold on`.

Comment: alright, I'll try it that way then. Thank you for the help! :-)